# About a result in Martin Davis' 1973 article "Hilbert's Tenth Problem is Unsolvable"

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

In Martin Davis, Hilbert's Tenth Problem is Unsolvable, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 80, No. 3 (Mar., 1973), pp. 233-269 ([link](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eshmuel/lg-readings/martin%20davis,%20hilbert%2010.pdf)), the author prove the following result:

**Theorem 3.1**: For given $a,x,k,a>1$, the system

(I) $x^2-(a^2-1)y^2=1$

(II) $u^2-(a^2-1)v^2=1$

(III) $s^2-(b^2-1)t^2=1$

(IV) $v=ry^2$

(V) $b=1+4py=a+qu$

(VI) $s=x+cu$

(VII) $t=k+4(d-1)y$

(VIII) $y=k+e-1$

has a solution in the remaining arguments $y,u,v,s,t,b,r,p,q,c,d,e$ if and only if $x=x_{k}(a)$. Here $x_{k}(a)$ pertains to the $k^{th}$ solution of Pell's equation (I), namely $(a + \sqrt{d})^k = x_k + y_k\sqrt{d}$ where $d = a^2 - 1$.

This theorem was used to prove that the exponential function $h(n,k)=n^{k}$ is Diophantine. The proof of this last result follows at once from the proof of the following lemma:

**Lemma**: $m=n^{k}$ if and only if equations I-VIII and

(IX) $(x-y(a-n)-m)^2=(f-1)^2(2an-n^2-1)^2$

(X) $m+g=2an-n^2-1$

(XI) $w=n+h=k+l$

(XII) $a^2-(w^2-1)(w-1)^2z^2=1$

have a solution in the remaining arguments.

I will add the proof of this result to clarify my questions:

**Proof**:  Suppose I-XII hold. By XI, $w>1$. Hence $(w-1)z>0$ and so by XII $a>1$. So Theorem 3.1 applies and it follows that $x=x_{k}(a),y=y_{k}(a)$.

By IX and Lemma 2.17, $$m\equiv n^k\pmod{2an-n^2-1}$$
XI yields $k,n<w$.  By XII (using Lemma 2.4, for some $j$, $a=x_{j}(w),(w-1)z=y_{j}(w)$.

By Lemma 2.14, $j\equiv 0\pmod {w-1}$, so that $j≥w-1$. So by Lemma 2.19, $a≥w^w-1>n^k$. Now by X, $m<an-n^2-1$, and by Lemma 3.4 $n^k<2an-n^2-1$
Since $m$ and $n^k$ are congruent and both less than the modulus, they must be equal.

Conversely, suppose that $m=n^{k}$. Solutions must be found for I-XII. Choose any number $w$ such that $w>n$ and $w>k$. Set $a=x_{w-1}(w)$ so that $a>1$. By Lemma 2.14, $y_{w-1}(w)\equiv 0\pmod {w-1}$. So one can write $y_{w-1}(w)≡z(w-1)$. Thus XII is satisfied. XI can be satisfied by setting $h=w-n,I=w-k$. As before, $a>n^{k}$ so that again by Lemma 3.4, $m=n^k<2an-n^2-1$ and X can be satisfied. Setting $x=x_{k}(a),y=y_{k}(a)$, Lemma 2.17 permits one to define$ f$ such that $$x-y(a-n)-m=±(f-1)(2an-n^2-1)$$ so that IX is satisfied. Finally, I-VIII can be satisfied by Theorem 3.1.

The cited results are proved in the cited paper. It seems to me that the choice of $a=x_{w-1}(w)$ is given only to prove that $a>1$. However, I am not sure about this.

Now, my **questions** are related to equation XII:

**(1)** Is the choice of $a=x_{w-1}(w)$ must be unique

**(2)** Can we replace XII by a simpler Pell equation such as: $a^2-(w^2-1)z^2=1$ to **avoid the dependence** of the indice (in the formula $a=x_{w-1}(w)$) by $w$ and **choosing any** $w$ such that all the required conditions for $a$ are satisfied. In this case, one can get $a=x_{j}(w)$ for some $j>1$ **independent** of $w$. This idea is based on the fact that $x_{j}(w)$ is **strictly increasing** with respect to $w$ and fixed $j$.

Comment: When solving such equations, such a situation often occurs. This is not the first time that transformations - there is a need through the relatively simple Pell equation. Write solutions. But in the process of solving other equations and accumulated experience suggests that simplifications do not give all the solutions. It will still be necessary to write all these heavy transformations. Here the situation is a little different.

Comment: If you make additional transformations, only then you can come up with a simpler Pell equation. The true form of it may be different.

Comment: @individ: Can you make this as an answer

Comment: When I solve my equations, I always operate with undefined coefficients. Look at my page how certain formulas can look like. But the reaction to this is extremely negative. So I think it's worth looking for a different approach.

Comment: @individ: Yes. I have read some of your solutions. But the situation here is very different.

Comment: I don't think there is any difference. There is one method for solving all the equations. Let's start with a simple one before solving such a complex problem? For example, there are a lot of squares. Can we try to solve the standard equation in uncertain coefficients?

Comment: @individ: The question is related to diophantine coding and depends mainly on the proof in the paper.

Comment: @individ: See my solution below.

Answer (score 1):

In the original proof of Davis, equation (XI) is used only to establish precisely that $w$ exceeds both $n$ and $k$.  As there are no other restrictions on $w$, the set of $w$ is infinite. Thus, we will prove that we can consider the simpler Pell's equation $$a^2-(w^2-1)z^2=1$$ instead of the former one.
Suppose I-XII hold. By XI, $w>1$. Hence all the solutions of the equation (XII) are $$a=x_{j}(w),z=y_{j}(w)$$ with $j≥1$. Thus, we can fix $j≥1$ and choosing $w$ such that $z>0$ and $a>1$ and these are the same required conditions in the first line of the proof of Davis. So Theorem 3.1 applies and it follows that $$x=x_{k}(a),y=y_{k}(a)$$

By IX and Lemma 2.17, $$m\equiv n^k\pmod{2an-n^2-1}$$

XI yields $k,n<w$. Since $x_{j}(w)$ is strictly increasing with respect to $w$ ($j$ fixed) and the set of $w$ is infinite, then there exist a positive integer $w_{0}$ such that $$a=x_{j}(w)>n^{k}$$ for any $w≥w_{0}$. We can choose any $w_{0}$ such that $w_{0}>n$ and $w_{0}>k$. Now by X, $m<an-n^2-1$, and by Lemma 3.4 we get $n^{k}<2an-n^2-1$. Since $m$ and $n^{k}$ are congruent and both less than the modulus, they must be equal.

Conversely, suppose that $m=n^{k}$. Solutions must be found for I-XII. Choose any number $w≥w_{0}$, then $w>n$ and $w>k$. Choose $a=x_{j}(w)$ with $j≥1$ fixed and any $w≥w_{0}$ so that $a>1$. By Lemma 2.4 $$a=x_{j}(w),z=y_{j}(w)$$

Thus XII is satisfied. XI can be satisfied by setting $$h=w-n,I=w-k$$

As before, $a=x_{j}(w)>n^{k}$ for any $w≥w_{0}$, so that again by Lemma 3.4, $m=n^{k}<2an-n^2-1$ and X can be satisfied. Setting $$x=x_{k}(a),y=y_{k}(a)$$

Lemma 2.17 permits one to define $f$ such that $$x-y(a-n)-m=±(f-1)(2an-n²-1)$$ so that IX is satisfied. Finally, I-VIII can be satisfied by Theorem 3.1.